# List of objects in Spring MVC @RequestBody produces "Syntactically incorrect request"

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, put

I'm trying to update an object via REST services using Spring MVC + Swagger Annotations. 
The method is something like this:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Modifies the entity")
@RequestMapping(value = "/entity", method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "Accept=application/json")
@APIMonitor
@ResponseBody
public PubTagger saveEntityDetails(
        HttpServletResponse response,
        ModelMap model,
        @RequestBody final EntityClass entityInfo
        )
        throws Exception {
         ...
        }
```

The entity definition is:

```
{
  "id": "long",  
  "description": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "value": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

It gives me an error

> The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()

But it only happens when I fill the objects inside the `Properties` field. If I leave it empty it succeeds. So I deduce there's something wrong in Spring MVC with nested objects inside lists.

Is there anything I'm missing here? Do I have to specify anything in the model to make it work?

Edit: Posting Entity class

```
public class Entity {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private List<Property> properties = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Entity() {
        super();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(final String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public List<Property> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(List<Property> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

}
```

Comment: post the `EntityClass` please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I found the error.

It was the class Property that only had the Parametrized constructor, without default constructor which made unable to marshall the JSON requestBody into an object.

Comment: you can annotate the parametrized constructor with @JsonCreator to make it work.

Comment: You can accept your answer or, if you post the Property class, I can write one with @JsonCreator used.